# Flask SQLAlchemy does not create all the columns of my model

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using flask and flask SQLAlchemy to create my sqllite database that has one table with several columns. I have created my model but once I run the app it only creates the first 03 columns ?!!!

```py
...

db = SQLAlchemy()

def setup_db(app):
    db.app = app
    db.init_app(app)

def db_drop_and_create_all():
    db.drop_all()
    db.create_all()

...

@dataclass
class ChurnModel(inheritedModels):
    id = int
    customerID = String
    gender = String
    SeniorCitizen: int
    Partner: String
    ...

    __tablename__ = 'churn'

    id = Column(Integer().with_variant(Integer, "sqlite"), primary_key=True)
    customerID = Column(String(255), nullable=False)
    gender = Column(String(255))
    SeniorCitizen: Column(Integer())
    Partner: Column(String(255))
    ...

    def get_churn(self):
        return {
            "id": self.id,
            "customerID": self.customerID,
            "gender": self.gender,
            "SeniorCitizen": self.SeniorCitizen,
            "Partner": self.Partner,
            ...
        }

    ...
```

This is what I have found in the `database.db` file surrounded by a lot of nulls:

```
TE TABLE churn (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    "customerID" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
    gender VARCHAR(255), 
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Any explanation?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking at the code, I think this is an expected behaviour since the only columns you defined are `id`, `customerID`, and `gender`.
Maybe you just got confused on how to use type hints, or you didn't pay attention to that, that's all.

Try this instead :

```py
@dataclass
class ChurnModel(inheritedModels):
    id: int
    customerID: str
    gender: str
    SeniorCitizen: int
    Partner: str
    ...

    __tablename__ = 'churn'

    id = Column(Integer().with_variant(Integer, "sqlite"), primary_key=True)
    customerID = Column(String(255), nullable=False)
    gender = Column(String(255))
    SeniorCitizen= Column(Integer())
    Partner= Column(String(255))
    ...
```